# Hidden data in JPEG bytes?

Tags: image, jpeg, image-compression

JPEG encodes in 8x8 blocks. My understanding is that if an image dimension is not an even multiple of 8, padding will be added to the image which is presumably cropped by the codec on decompression.

- What color is this padding?
- Isn't there an opportunity to hide information in these unseen pixels?

You could potentially have a 7-pixel bar at the side and bottom populated with whatever content you want only viewable by a customized decoder (basically stenography).

Finally why aren't there tools that scour the web looking for cool hidden messages? Why isn't this phenomenon mentioned more often?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to extend the last pixel. You can put anything you want into this data and it should decode correctly.

As to why, who knows?